# How can I include ratings in the site, with reference stored in the node table?

Tags: entities, nodes, rating

I need to implement ratings for my site. I have already stored the data in the node; now, I need to store the average ratings point in the node field type which I have created. It must be the reference for the ratings table.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Have you done your coding to rate & store the value in DB ?

Comment: no Rajeev , i didn't get idea how to use ratings in my site if you explain me let me do.

Comment: In case you might want to re-think your approach into an out-of-the-box solution you can use the Fivestart module.

Comment: ok Potney Switters thanks for the reply, can please explain how to include ratings plugin and how to give reference to the node .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module for this.

> The Fivestar voting module adds a clean, attractive voting widget to nodes in Drupal 5, node and comments in Drupal 6, and any entity in Drupal 7.

You configure which content type should have the Fivestar module enabled; you can also set the permissions for the users who can vote etc. You will have multiple option to show the vote result on the configuration page of module.

I have used it in 3-4 e-commerce websites and it works simply great.

Comment: @Bala007 Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your probelm. Thanks :)

Comment: still i am not solving the problem rajeev, i install the fivestar module , and now i need to display the ratings star in the custom module where i used form to create and stored values now i need to store the ratings in the node when the user  select the node can you give me some suggestion how can we do

Comment: @Bala007 You can open ask a different question with more explanation with your need as I don't understand what are you asking.